# Running LoadTest from SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

How can I run a LoadTest under a Test Case in SOAPUI Pro from test suite level? Only the Test Steps get executed when I run the Test Case and not the Load test under it.

Is there a way to run the LoadTest other than directly accessing 'Run this Loadtest' from the LoadTest.

Please help

Comment: Which version of ReadyAPI are you using? And did you happened to see [documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/loadui_ng/start)?

Comment: Rao,I use SOAP UI Pro 5.1.2.

Comment: If you got pro license, you may use the same license for ReadyAPI which is the latest software.

Comment: Hi Rao, true. I shall do that. But, I am trying to know how I can run the load test along with test steps. Ie) I need to run the load test as the TC is run. Currently, when  I run the test case from SOAPUI, I don't get the load test running, only the teststeps are executed

Comment: Have you gone thru the above link?